# Changing Server's default page

Tags: centos

I have a server (and a static IP), but not have a domain yet.
But i still want to use it with IP address and upload my web page.

When I write the IP address, I am redirected to a `cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` default website page.

How can I change it, so it will read `/var/www/html/index.php` as default.

Server is Centos 6.0 and I fave Cpanel

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

- Backup your current defaultwebpage.cgi
- Overwrite the above file, with the following 2 lines.

  ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   print "Location: http://IP_ADDR/index.php\n\n";
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To change the "Default Website Page" on a WHM/cPanel CENTOS 6 Server I need to:

- Go to: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/
- Backup everything there to a safespot
- Replace index.html with the new version
- Upload any supporting files

Your new index.html should show when you access the machine via IP Address or exact Server Domain Name.

I learned this from here:
http://www.limecanvas.com/changing-the-cpanel-default-website-page/